# Anonymous classes extension

Tags: java, class, anonymous

When declaring an anonymous class like in the following:

Note that ResourceBundle.Control is a concrete class.

Snippet taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/examples/RBControl.java).

```
private static void test(Locale locale) {
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ResourceBundle", locale,
         new ResourceBundle.Control() {
         @Override
         public List<Locale> getCandidateLocales(String baseName, Locale locale) {
             if (baseName == null)
             throw new NullPointerException();
             if (locale.equals(new Locale("it", "IT"))) {
             return Arrays.asList(
                 locale,
                 Locale.ITALY,
                 Locale.CHINESE ,
                 Locale.ROOT);
             } else if (locale.equals(Locale.GERMANY)) {
             return Arrays.asList(
                 locale.GERMANY,
                 // no Locale.CHINESE here
                 Locale.ROOT);
             }
             return super.getCandidateLocales(baseName, locale);
         }
         });
```

I see basically that the keywork `extends` it's not used when declaring the anonymous class. Does it take it for granted? If so when is appropriate to use `extends` in anonymous classes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> when is appropriate to use `extends` in anonymous classes?

Never. Keyword `extends` is appropriate for named classes, which can implement interfaces in addition to extending classes. In contrast, anonymous classes can either implement an interface or extend a class, but not both. That is why the syntax has no keyword at all - just put curly braces after a `new` expression, and provide implementation for the methods of your base class or an interface.

Comment: +1. In particular, the anonymous class cannot implement multiple interfaces. Inconvenient at times. When you need that, you need to make a "proper" named class.

Comment: @Thilo I agree, this is often an inconvenience. One could mitigate this to an extent by defining an abstract class that implements several related interfaces, and using that class as a base for anonymous types in different situations. `DefaultCellRenderer` class in java swing is a good example of this trick, with implementations of `Accessible`, `ImageObserver`, `ListCellRenderer`, and `MenuContainer`. However, sometimes you just need several interfaces, and you can't get it without a named class.

Comment: Therefore it goes that it's implicitly extending. Thanks

Comment: @Rollerball ...or implicitly implementing, if the type name denotes an interface.